# nginx https ssl and aws-sdk upload with node.js error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

Everyting worked fine with upload but after I added ssl to my server and switched to https I get this error.

UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `boja.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' at port` undefined'. This service may not be available in the `eu-west-2' region.

code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
region: 'eu-west-2',
hostname: 'boja.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
retryable: true,
originalError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN boja.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:82:26) {
errno: -3001,
code: 'NetworkingError'

the only thing that is changed is my nginx cofig file.
What are the steps that I need to change after I switched to https?
My nginx conf file

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  client_max_body_size 999M;
  server_name finance.ba;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /api {
      proxy_pass http://api;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/finance.ba/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/finance.ba/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = finance.ba) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80;
  server_name finance.ba;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```